# Netbeans IDE for C++ how to specify command line arguments

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, command-line

How do I specify command line arguments for a netbeans C++ project?

There does not seem to be a suitable place on debug tab.

Answer (score 27):

To specify command line arguments for a C++ project in netbeans go to:

`Project properties` => `Run` => `Run Command`

The default is:

`"${OUTPUT_PATH}"`

Change that to:

`"${OUTPUT_PATH}" hi 5`

The create main.cpp with this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "First argument: " << argv[1] << endl;
    cout << "Second argument: " << argv[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces output:

```
First argument: hi
Second argument: 5

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 320ms)
```

Comment: So as to this each and everytime we want to run with different parameters we have to set them going through `Project properties => Run => Run Command` or is there another way.

Comment: To modify project setting every time - alas I have to say it's not so handy as Eclipse's run/debug configurations, which can be accessed and managed much faster. Not exactly a criticism, rather just my conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple Run/Debug configuration for different arguments (or different executable) using Project Properties -> Run -> Manage Configurations -> New. Then you can add the commands/arguments there. 
In the main editor, the "Run" toolbar has a drop down that you can select desired configuration then you can use the Run/Debug button with this configurations