# .open files using argc and argv in C++

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have some code Which is supposed to open two .dat file at the same time and eventually load the files over to a method to deal with them. I am not sure how to load the two files in using the code I have been given. I will show below.

This is my main

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
// Start main class with command-line args



GPXport run(argc, argv);
return 0; 
}
```

This is the code part to load in the files.

```
ofstream output;

// Open files
file_one.open(argv[1]);
file_two.open(argv[2]);
output.open(argv[3]);

if (! file_one) {
    cout << "Error reading: " << argv[1] << endl;
} else if (! file_two) {
    cout << "Error reading: " << argv[2] << endl;
} else if (! output) {
    cout << "Error creating: " << argv[2] << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Master: " << argv[1] << endl <<
            "Slave: " << argv[2] << endl <<
            "Output file: " << argv[3] << endl;
}
```

Now the problem is, I do not understand the argv and argc situation. How do i get the two file locations to this code?

Thanks

Edit---

I also have this before the second part of the code..

```
 GPXport::GPXport(int argc, char **argv)  
 {
using namespace std;
if (argc != 4) {
    cout << "Usage: ./gpsfix_cpp <master> <slave> <output>" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
```

Comment: You may find this useful as well; http://stackoverflow.com/q/3024197/3747990

Comment: " "Error creating: " << argv[2] " - or [3] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run compiled executable from command line as:

```
[your executable] [input path1] [input path2] [output path]
```

if any path contains spaces quote the path.

Comment: I am trying to find my executable project from netbeans.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672072/netbeans-ide-for-c-how-to-specify-command-line-arguments your executable is in "${OUTPUT_PATH}"